# After update to Mac OS 10.8: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"; "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1"

Tags: macos, clang, osx-mountain-lion, linker-errors, x86-64

After updating a new Mac (OS 10.8), my colleague and I are unable to compile a C++ code that we have been using.  We are not experienced with coding and would be very grateful if someone could point us in the right direction at a newbie level.  We see that there are many posts on this type of error, but if any of them are relevant, we don't see how, except that the posts all seem to say that this is likely to be a linker problem.

When we do "make," there is a lot of output.  The first part is this:

> Us$ make g++ -o ourProg 1.o main.o 2.o -L/Prog/libraries
>   -L/Prog/support_libraries -l_codea -l_codeb ...  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

The final part is this:

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make: ***
>   [ourProg] Error 1

Unfortunately, a condition of using the code is that we can't post it online, so it may be that there is not enough information that anyone can help.

The thing that stands out for me is that it looks like Clang is being used for linking, even though we have specifically said we want g++ to be used for compiling. In the makefile, we have said:

> CC = g++

Comment: Had this problem myself. Remove xCode and reinstall from app store.

Comment: @developer82. Sorry for being such an idiot, but could you please clarify?  We already reinstalled XCode from the Apple site and it made no difference.  Are you saying that there's an app store with a different version?

Comment: Mac comes with it's own app store (you can find it in launcher) and you can install xCode from there. that helped me when I was having troubles.

Comment: Why not take the free update to 10.9? The hardware support coverage is the same. Also, the information here only narrows it down to some kind of linker error. It could be a missing/misconfigured system library, or it could be something else.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, I didn't know that.  Do you think this would not be a problem in 10.9?  We're under a pretty tight deadline and would not want to update to 10.9 unless it would solve the current problem--just in case other issues would arise!  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: To be of any help, I would have to know what symbols were undefined, then track down where they should be defined -- system library or your code, which would lead to why they were missed in the link step.

Comment: @user3292696 Upgrading is far more likely to resolve issues IMHO. Anyway the toolchain should behave the same using the 10.8 SDK from a 10.9 installation. You can run 10.8 or 10.9 in a VM, so you could also download VirtualBox and do an install in the background with minimal fuss, just to try and see.

Comment: (Oh, and by the way, GNU make appears to be hardwired with `ld` naming the linker in the default rule, not `$CC`; see http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html .)

Answer (score 4):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Thanks everyone; the problem is solved. I'm not sure whether to indicate this anywhere in the question, sorry. I'd like to describe how we fixed it, in case any other newbies are having trouble understanding the more sophisticated posts on this problem!
>
> First, we followed the advice here by updating to OS 10.9 and installing the new command line tools. Then we came across a forum post that discussed where the linking problem comes from. In OS 10.8 and 10.9, the C++ default standard libraries are different. So we first added a new include to our makefile:

```
/usr/bin/clang++
```

> Then we added to the compiler flag line and the libraries:

```
-stdlib=libstdc++
```